# Topology cheat sheet

Tags: modeling, topology, unity

Where is a good source for image examples of reducing and increasing quad amounts. i.e. 5 to 1, 4 to 1. etc. [image]

Edit: What I'm trying to create is a slide for a weapon. That has good topology for video games.[image]

Comment: It all depends on the situation and on the final goal, also sometimes it's not a problem to have tris. What are you trying to achieve exactly, what is your final object?

Comment: Thanks for showing the final object but it doesn't look like your first mesh, also I'm still not sure why you need quads, as I and Martynas say you could use tris and even ngons

Comment: @moonboots My models are used for game design and can be animated/scaled. They cannot have Ngons.

Comment: yes but they can have tris i guess?

Answer (score 3):

A good website about topology is [topologyguides](https://topologyguides.com/). Example he gives of quad reduction:

[image]

That said, maybe you should explain what you're trying to achieve and why you're looking for only quads, tris are probably OK in your case, even ngons can be OK as long as it doesn't create artefacts and doesn't hinder your modeling:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You should have geometry where you need it to hold the form of your object, where you plan to use some sort deformations in the future(rigging, animation) and where you plan to use some other tools and modelling techniques, but nowhere else. In some cases there are techniques that use geometry to fix shading, those are fine too, but it's also possible to fix shading other ways.

This can be almost perfect topology:

[image]

In your case there is actually no purpose for all those edges. Is there? What is the reason to have them? You could be tempted to think of reasons that *may* apply, but do you actually have them in your situation? In my case, I actually also left some completely useless edges only because of my personal superstition that it's "bad luck" to have concave n-gons. The truth is the top part is flat and does not need any edges in the middle to hold it's shape. Why do things without any reason?

There are plenty of good reasons to have various kinds of geometry there. If you have geometry just because it looks and feels nicer to you without any reason(Let's admit, we all do it :D ), that's also fine, just be honest with yourself. I see little logic in those topology guides and all the rules. The way I see it, sure, you make geometry exactly how those guides advice, but it's not because of the guides, it must be because of the reasons behind them. You should always have a reason, not some rule from a book, other way, it's just a waste of your time.